# Error Msg 1033 al crear VISTA SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Al crear una VISTA en SQL SERVER (SQL Server Management Studio  15.0.18384.0)  me genera un error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

El código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE VIEW vwdiasEnfermedad AS 
WITH EventosDesplegados AS (SELECT   Fk_TipoEvento,Fk_Usuario, FechaInicio,FechaInicio AS Fecha
                        FROM Eventos
                        WHERE Fk_TipoEvento = 3

                        UNION ALL               
                        
                        SELECT   e.Fk_TipoEvento, e.Fk_Usuario, e.FechaInicio, DATEADD(DAY, 1, ed.Fecha)
                        FROM Eventos e
                        INNER JOIN EventosDesplegados ed ON e.Fk_Usuario = ed.Fk_Usuario AND 
                                                             e.FechaInicio = ed.FechaInicio
                        WHERE   DATEADD(DAY, 1, ed.Fecha) < e.FechaFin),

   EventosNumerados AS (SELECT  Fk_TipoEvento, Fk_Usuario, CONVERT(char(25), ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), Fecha, 126), ' '))Fecha , 
                          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fk_Usuario ORDER BY Fecha ASC)AS orden
                   FROM EventosDesplegados 
                   WHERE Fk_TipoEvento = 3 AND  YEAR(FechaInicio) = YEAR (GETDATE()))
SELECT U.USUARIOID,
   ISNULL(U.NOMBRE + ' ' + U.APELLIDOPATERNO + ' ' + U.APELLIDOMATERNO,'NO EXISTE/TEST') AS Nombre,
   CASE WHEN EN.Fk_TipoEvento=3  THEN 3-count(*) ELSE 3 END AS DiasDisponibles ,
   MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 1 THEN  Fecha ELSE 'Disponible' END  ) AS 'DiaDeEnfermedad1',
   MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 2 THEN Fecha ELSE 'Disponible' END) AS 'DiaDeEnfermedad2',
   MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 3 THEN Fecha ELSE 'Disponible' END) AS 'DiaDeEnfermedad3'
FROM EventosNumerados AS EN
FULL JOIN USUARIO AS U ON U.USUARIOID = EN.Fk_Usuario 
GROUP BY U.USUARIOID, U.NOMBRE, U.APELLIDOPATERNO, U.APELLIDOMATERNO,EN.Fk_TipoEvento
ORDER BY U.USUARIOID ASC;
```

Con lo siguiente se soluciona error pero no respeta el orden de código anterior:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT U.USUARIOID,.......
```

¡Saludos, Comunidad!

Comment: Qué versión de SQL Server usas? Por favor, edita la pregunta para indicarlo

Comment: Listo..........

Comment: Esa es la versión del cliente, Sql Server Management Studio. Debes revisar la salida de ejecutar `Select @@version` al conectarte a la BD.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 19043: )

Comment: El error es tal cual lo que dice, no puedes usar una clausula `ORDER BY` en una lista, elimina la misma y en todo caso ordena desde la selección de la vista.

Comment: Muchas Gracias..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes utilizar ORDER BY U.USUARIOID ASC; en una vista, mas bien al momento de consumirla haces el order by

Comment: Muchas Gracias..